# PHP MySQL query outputs only a two-element array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I just made a quick little script with SQL query.
Now when I go to phpmyadmin and execute

```
SELECT name FROM players WHERE online='1' ORDER BY name ASC
```

It outputs the desired players ( 0TheMonk, Player, Veeve )

But with PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM players WHERE online='1' ORDER BY name ASC");
$query_array=mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo implode(',',$query_array);
```

It echoes: 0TheMonk,0TheMonk

Instead of: 0TheMonk,Player,Veeve

It always outputs the first player in the array, twice. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` only returns one row.  See the docs: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 2):

Use `while` loop

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM players WHERE online='1' ORDER BY name ASC");
while($query_array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $query_array['name'].",";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually helped, but now I have every player twice.
0TheMonk,0TheMonkPlayer,PlayerVeeve,Veeve
That's even more weird O.o

Comment: Thank you so so so so much! <3

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Almost same as Sumits answer.

```
$res    = array();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM players WHERE online='1' ORDER BY name ASC");
while($query_array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $res[]   = $query_array['name'];
}

echo implode(",",$res);
```

In this case there will not a extra `,` at the ens